# Simulate a generic class in PHP

Tags: php, generics, phpdoc

I'm trying to implement a Results class that processes queries.  So, simply put, you would have functions like this:

```
function all();
function first();
function paginate(int $perPage, int $pageNo = 1);
```

This works pretty well, the problem being that the IDE has no possible way of knowing the return type when this same results class is being used in multiple different query classes.  Example:

`UserQuery->results()->all()` will return an array of User entities.

`UserQuery->results()->first()` will return a single User entity.

In some languages, you have generics, which means I could just use `Results<User>` in the UserQuery class and then my Results class could return `T[]` and `T` respectively.

One idea I had was to pass an empty entity as the constructor to the Results class and then try to use that property as the return type, but I couldn't figure this out.   Is there any workaround to this?   The main problem I'm trying to solve is IDE autocompletion and analysis, so a pure phpDoc solution is perfectly fine for my use case.

The only other workaround I can come up with is having to write a separate Results class for each entity type, which would prove to be exhausting.

Comment: In Eclipse and PHP storm, you can manually do a type hint like this `/* @var $foo Users */`  such as right before a loop so that the `as $foo` part will have autocomplete.

Comment: Yes, that's what I normally end up doing when the IDE doesn't detect the right type.  Unfortunately, that ends up with writing almost as much code as the last option, as I have to document the return value on every usage instead of just where it's defined.  It's also not very refactor friendly.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you described, but in similar cases I would suggest using a proxy class for each Results type and document proper return types using phpDocumentor's [@method](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html). This solution has added value of having a great place for any type specific Results modifications and expansions. Here's an example:

```
abstract class Results
{
    function all(): array
    {
    }

    function first()
    {
    }

    function paginate(int $perPage, int $pageNo = 1): array
    {
    }
}

class User { }

/**
 * @method User[] all()
 * @method User first()
 * @method User[] paginate(int $perPage, int $pageNo = 1)
 */
class UserResults extends Results { }

class UserQuery
{
    /**
     * @var UserResults
     */
    private $results;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->results = new UserResults();
    }

    public function results(): UserResults
    {
        return $this->results;
    }
}

$userQuery = new UserQuery();
$test = $userQuery->results()->all();
```

[image: PhpStorm correctly recognises returned type]

Comment: Only now I noticed your comment about "separate Results class for each entity type, would prove to be exhausting" but imho in the proposed form those Results implementation classes could be easily autogenerated and would not cost any additional work.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is when the abstract class changes or a new method is introduced, I'd have to re-write the PHPDoc on ~30 child classes, thank you for putting this together though, I'm sure it can help others that may come across it.